# Error "tether.on is not a function."

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Uno de los efectos **JavaScript** de mi barra de navegación, que se activa al hacer `scroll`, desapareció, vi en mi consola y me tira este error:

```
TypeError: tether.on is not a function. (In 'tether.on', 'tether.on' is undefined)
(función anónima) — redessociales:781
each — jquery.js:123
each — jquery.js:30
(función anónima) — redessociales:735
i — jquery.js:1002
fireWith — jquery.js:1039:94
ready — jquery.js:1105:110
K — jquery.js:1112:105
```

Probé borrando un formulario `mailchimp` que ingresé recientemente en mi `sidebar`, pero nada.
Agradezco su ayuda!

Comment: ese stacktrace no sirve de mucho sin el código. te sugiero que copies el codigo relevante para que podamos ayudarte. Salu2

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te esta diciendo es que ***tether.on*** todavía no es una función. Esto es porque se esta llamando a la función pero todavía no se cargo. Y no se cargo porque o esta mal la ruta del archivo .js o porque se define la función después que el llamado a la función. Por favor verificar esto.